# d3js interact with text inside a node using mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

I'm modifying the following [Zoomable Circle Packing example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535)

The problem I am facing is that the json I am using contains many fields with long text lines. This drives a situation where the labels of each node overlaps with the near ones.

I am thinking in two options:
* Rotate the text 45º 
* Hide the labels by default and use the mouseover function to show it when necessary

I can interact with nodes' colour depending data but I have failed interacting with text characteristics to rotate or hide|display the text inside a node.

Can anyone pointing me in the right direction?

This is my test code to hide the node's text when the mouse is over (once this is done I will do the opposite, hidden by default and visible when the mouse is over):

```
 var text = svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
  .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("visibility", "hidden");});
```

Thanks for your comment @jkhan I have tried both pieces of code without success. (nothing happens)

This one for mouse :

```
 var widthThreshold = 100;
 var text = svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
  .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .select('text')
  .attr('opacity', function(d){
    return this.getBBox().width > widthThreshold ? .001 : 1;
  })
  .on('mouseover', function(){
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity', 1);
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(){
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity', function(){
       return this.getBBox().width > widthThreshold ? .001 : 1;
    });
  });
```

And this one for rotation:

```
 var widthThreshold = 100;
 var text = svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
  .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .select('text')
  .attr('transform', function(d){
    return this.getBBox().width > widthThreshold ? 'rotate(90)' : '';
  });
```

Comment: Can you post your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @jsfiddle code added

Answer (score 0):

For rotation, you should be able to use the transform attribute:

```
var widthThreshold = 100;

relevantSelection
    .select('text')
    .attr('transform', function(d){
        return this.getBBox().width > widthThreshold ? 'rotate(90)' : '';
    });
```

I think you are already on the right track for show/hide on mouseover:

```
relevantSelection
    .select('text')
    .attr('opacity', function(d){
        return this.getBBox().width > widthThreshold ? .001 : 1;
    })
    .on('mouseover', function(){
        d3.select(this).attr('opacity', 1);
    })   
    .on('mouseout', function(){
        d3.select(this).attr('opacity', function(){
           return this.getBBox().width > widthThreshold ? .001 : 1;
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have updated the question with my piece of code with your code (@jkhan) added and nothing happens. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've made it work modifying the pointer-events parameters from:

```
.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

to

```
.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```